# Return rows only if they are different that previous days value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
sales
-id
-user_id
-amount
-datetime
```

the sales table gets a new record for each user_id daily.

i want a select query that returns me all rows for the current day, only if the 'amount' is different that the previous days.

Update

```
5   123    700  2017/01/05
4   123    500  2017/01/04
3   123   1500  2017/01/03
2   123   1500  2017/01/02
1   123    500  2017/01/01
```

So if you search for records on the 5th, you will get 1 row since it is different that the previous days.

```
5   123    700  2017/01/05
```

But if you were run the query on the 3rd, since the amound $1500 is the same as on the 2nd, you will get 0 results back.

Hope this clears it up.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: You have far more than enough reputation to know how to ask a question. Provide Sample data (in the form of a `CREATE` and `INSERT` statement) and your expected results. Then someone will be able to help you. :)

Comment: @Larnu I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the Lead() and Lag() SQL Analytic function for this

```
SELECT *
from (SELECT *, LAG(AMOUNT) over (partition by user_id order by datetime) as Yesterday_AMOUNT
      from SALES s
     ) x
where cast(s.datetime as date) = cast(getdaate() as date) and 
       x.AMOUNT <> s.Yesterday_AMOUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
select *
from (select *, lag(amount) over (partition by user_id order by datetime) as prev_amt
      from sales s
     ) s
where cast(s.datetime as date) = cast(getdaate() as date) and 
       s.amount <> s.prev_amt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query helps if ONLY one amount is commited every day. 
First of all need to find previous amount. You can use analytics function lag() over().

```
 select *
    from (
        select *
            , lag(amount) over (partition by id order by datetime) as prev_amount
        from sales
        ) as t1 
    where prev_amount <> amount
        and trunc(datetime) = 'today'
```

Answer (score -1):

This Query Will Help YOu

```
SELECT  r1.Code, r1.Date, r1.Rate
FROM    RateTable r1
WHERE   r1.Rate <> (SELECT TOP 1 Rate
               FROM    RateTable
               WHERE   Date < r1.Date
               ORDER BY Date DESC)
```