# Return rows if the column value is different than the previous days record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a select query that returns me all rows for the current day, only if the 'amount' is different that the previous days.

```
sales
-id
-user_id
-amount
-datetime
```

The sales table gets a new record for each user_id daily.

An example scenerio would be as follows:

```
5   123    700  2017/01/05
4   123    500  2017/01/04
3   123   1500  2017/01/03
2   123   1500  2017/01/02
1   123    500  2017/01/01
```

So if you search for records on the Jan. 5th, you will get 1 row since it is different that the previous days (700 vs 500).

result:

```
5   123    700  2017/01/05
```

But if you were run the query on the 3rd, since the amound $1500 is the same as on the 2nd, you will get 0 results back.

I have this basic join but I need to somehow compare the current days row from s1 and compare that with the previous days amount value.

```
select s1.*
from sales as s1
    inner join sales s2 on s1.user_id = s2.user_id and s1.datetime = s2.datetime
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY the same question you posted yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385491/return-rows-only-if-they-are-different-that-previous-days-value We can't see your screen or read your mind. What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Incorrect results?

Comment: @SeanLange incorrect results, it is just joining on the same days result.

Comment: Try using on the `JOIN` statement: `s1.DateTime = DateAdd(Day,-1,s2.DateTime) AND s1.Amount <> s2.Amount`. I would use a `LEFT JOIN` though. What if this is the first entry for that userid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858861/1507566

Answer (score 1):

You basically have the query.  You just need the date arithmetic:

```
select s.*
from sales s left join
     sales sprev
     on sprev.user_id = s.user_id and sprev.datetime = dateadd(day, -1, s.datetime)
where s.datetime = '2018-01-05' and
      (s.amount <> sprev.amount or sprev.amount is null);
```

Comment: Don't you mean `s.amount <> sprev.amount` in the `Where`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA . . . That would be what the OP is asking for.  Thank you.